# Https domain is different from http domain?

Tags: hosting, dns

I bought a new domain for my site, and when I access http://www.mysite.com i can see my site, but when I access https://www.mysite.com, I see a completely different site.

Is this a normal thing? I thought if I buy this domain, nobody can use it. Is this normal?

Thanks

Comment: It's technically possible, but it's not normal for a hosting provider to do so (google spam?). Contact your hosting provider.

Comment: The way the question is worded indicate that you probably didn't _buy_ a domain name, but merely _rented hosting services_ along with a loan for the _url_ (not the _domain name_), apparently tied to the http protocol alone.  You should inquire with your hosting service provider for details and/or post this kind of questions to serverfault.com or maybe webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The domain is the same but the webserver could be serving two different sites for http and https. The server can make this distinction since those 2 protocols listen on different ports.

In short, talk to your hosting provider.